# Find location of a checkbox inside a table

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a table that has checkboxes within tds. The checkboxes have ids that form an array (s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], etc...) and I am trying to find out the numeric row location of the checkbox within the table>tbody (YES, this row location also matches the index inside the array. Here's the code I'm trying but the result is always "0":

```
    $('input:checkbox').bind('change',function() {
        var thisRow = $('tbody tr').index();
        $('input:text[id=qty[' + thisRow + ']').attr('readonly','false')
        .focus();
        alert(thisRow);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$('input:checkbox').bind('change',function() {
    var thisRowindex = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
    ...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DEEKy/2/

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).closest('tr').index()` should also work

Answer (score 0):

From a combination of all these excellent answers, I have come up with this:

```
    $('input:checkbox').bind('change',function() {
        $(this).closest('input:text[id^=qty]').removeAttr('readonly').focus();
    });
```

But, it's still not allowing input to nor focusing on the  box that's at the end of the same row in the table. Any thoughts?